# Finding out where it inherited the data in BackboneJS

Tags: inheritance, backbone.js, model

I've been studying BackboneJS daily in order to help with debugging/fixing issues on our application. I've been putting tons of breakpoint in our application specifically on "this" so I can check the inherited data. Last week I got so confused that the "this" contained multiple models.

```
this.objectAItem
this.objectBItem
```

Is there a function in BackboneJS where it will tell us where the "this" inherited the data from?

UPDATE:

```
  onSubmit: function onSubmit() {
    this.patientModel.set('hasSubmitted', true);
    this.validateInput();
    if (this.patientModel.isValid()) {
      this.validationSyncRequest();
    } else {
      this.setValidationError();
      this.view.hideLoading();
    }
    this.view.render();
  },
```

However, when I console.log(this), I also see another model and ".get" works on it.

```
console.log(this.patientModel.get('id');
console.log(this.itemModel.get('dateCreated');
```

So I am not sure where it inherited itemModel from.

Comment: Couldn't you provide some code where you try to use `this` just to make your question a little bit clearer?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I updated my post above.

Comment: As you, probably, know, in `Backbone.js` you use functions such as `Backbone.Model.extend()`, `Backbone.View.extend()`, `Backbone.Router.extend()`, `Backbone.Collection.extend()` to define new behaviour and state for corresponding objects. You can use `this` inside `extend()`. 
`this` refers to current model object inside `Backbone.Model.extend()`.
Similarly `this` refers to current view object  inside `Backbone.View.extend()`. And so on.

Comment: Each of  model/view/collection/router objects has some predefined properties that can be accessible using 'this'.
For example, you always can access `this.el` property inside `Backbone.View.extend()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will check them out.